# how to see data of user specified through django-table2?

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter, django-tables2

Hello i want to make a table where one can see only his created rows and not others so i have specified a user for everyrow
previously i used it like this -

```
def see(request):
    as=A.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'m/see.html',{'as':as})
```

this was working perfectly fine later i rendered a table through Django table 2
my tables .py is

```
class ATable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        exclude = ('aid',)
        per_page = 2
```

i want to make it user specific so that i can only see data entered from myuserid not all
my filter.py code is

```
class AFilter(df.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        exclude = ('aid',)
```

kindly help what and where should i write to specify the user

**Updated- Views.py**

```
class AList(PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = A
    template_name = "m/see.html"
    table_class = ATable
    filter_class = AFilter
    formhelper_class = AListFormHelper
```

**Utils.py**

```
from django_tables2 import SingleTableView
from django_tables2.config import RequestConfig

class PagedFilteredTableView(SingleTableView):
    filter_class = None
    formhelper_class = None
    context_filter_name = 'filter'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(PagedFilteredTableView, self).get_queryset()
        self.filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        self.filter.form.helper = self.formhelper_class()
        return self.filter.qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PagedFilteredTableView, self).get_context_data()
        context[self.context_filter_name] = self.filter
        return context
```

Comment: Does PagedFilteredTableView inherit from SingleTableView ?

Comment: yes class PagedFilteredTableView(SingleTableView): shall i enter code of that too ? Updated in Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `get_queryset` method like following.

```
class AList(PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = A
    template_name = "m/see.html"
    table_class = ATable
    filter_class = AFilter
    formhelper_class = AListFormHelper

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(AList, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

Comment: is not helping same results i can see all the rows.

Comment: can you print the query and see what is inside the query. print(qs.query)

Comment: i am sorry i am a new person in this field  kindly instruct how to do that exactly

Comment: You can use a debugging tool like this https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/
or the IDE should have debugging tool integrated. BTW, does the model A has a user field?

Comment: yes model A has user field-  
user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)